# Using ES6 modules in non-modular Angular app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6

I've got the following question. Is it possible to start using ES6 modules in Angular & ES5 app. So that the application is so to say partially modular.

Comment: Without more details, all I can really answer is 'Yes, it probably is'. Could you give a more detailed description of your current project and, preferably, a minimal example that you would like to add an ES6 module to?

Comment: Actually the goal is to make the whole application modular step by step. For instance, we have directives, each in their own module. And there is common module for all directives. And the question is how to implement that common module in the application?

Comment: Even so, I think it would be hard to answer this without at least a little more information. Could you at least describe your project layout, build tools etc?

Comment: We use Gulp as task runner to minify, uglify, concanenate and so on, actually the layout needs reconsideration. And we're in the process of doing it. The app has 1 angular module and all the instances (controllers, services, directives) are defined on that module. Don't ask me why is it so.